# Turning a long line of text into a paragraph with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to turn a long line of text from a variable into a paragraph, how can I do this in CSS?

Comment: If you want to add text from JS variable then you have to use JS for it.

Comment: I doing it through a Express.js server.

Comment: Please add some example code and outline what you have tried to date. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't have any because I don't know any CSS.

Comment: We need somewhere to start. How did the text get into the variable? How does the user enter the text? What HTML/javascript do you already have that creates the situation you alredy have?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to turn a long line of text into a paragraph using CSS, why do you need to all that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I get the question right you have some javascript variable and you just want to wrap it in a `<p>` element. It goes like this:
`<p><script type = "text/javascript>document.write(yourvariablename);</script></p>`
Check this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp
Also check out how you can fill up the paragraph with the javascript variable instead of putting js code in the html. You should separate javascript from html in situations like this for clarity's sake

Also I think you want to use CSS to style the paragraph it goes like this:

```
`<style>
p{
  width:60%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
</style>`
```

- example of a 60% wide paragraph that is centered in it's parent

Comment: why the downvote? Just answering what the OP asked!